# beginner - trying to get jquery to insert elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hey So Im trying to get javascript/jquery to insert some box divs into my DOM - can't figure out why it's not working. Care to assist me?
Check it out here:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gobcd

Edit (code):

```
$document.ready(
    for(i=0; i<17; i++){
        $("#square_holder").append("<div class='block'></div>");
    };

    button.onclick=function(){
        console.log("Prior grid setup cleared. Next you will be prompted for a new amount.")
        var newnumber = gets.chomp;
        console.log("You entered: #{newnumber}. Watch in awe as the grid fills ..... ")
};
);
```

Comment: I can not open that url from my current location, please include code with question

Comment: @NappingRabbit -- I got ya!

Comment: Per the code: Your DOM ready handler is wrong, change to `$(document).ready(function() {` -- Also, what is `button`?

Comment: Just start over with learning Javascript and jQuery, there are too many syntax errors in there to deduct that you lack even the basics.

Comment: yeh looks like if you change your ready handler as mentioned you will insert 16 empty `DIV`s when your page loads.

Comment: @NappingRabbit, yes! this code will change society as we know it! Seriously, if he's learning that could be what he's after?

Comment: try to read jquery documentation

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your code:

```
$document.ready(
    for (i = 0; i < 17; i++) {
        $("#square_holder").append("<div class='block'></div>");
    };
    button.onclick = function () {
        console.log("Prior grid setup cleared. Next you will be prompted for a new amount.")
        var newnumber = gets.chomp;
        console.log("You entered: #{newnumber}. Watch in awe as the grid fills ..... ")
    }; 
);
```

You haven't defined `$document` as far as I can see, I suspect what you actually meant was:

```
$(document).ready(
```

Next you need to pass a function reference to the ready function, so it should be:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
```

Then you haven't declared a variable called `button`, so that line should probably be:

```
$('button').click(function() {
    // your code
});
```

Making all of those changes, the new code should probably look something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    for (i = 0; i < 17; i++) {
        $("#square_holder").append("<div class='block'></div>");
    };
    $('button').click(function () {
        console.log("Prior grid setup cleared. Next you will be prompted for a new amount.")
        var newnumber = gets.chomp;
        console.log("You entered: #{newnumber}. Watch in awe as the grid fills ..... ")
    }); 
});
```

Then there are a few issues with your HTML. The `<script>` tags can probably be moved to inside the `<head>` tag, or at the least should be moved before the `</body>` tag. On a related note, you're trying to load a stylesheet and script that can't be found.

You also need to change the `<div>` after `<div id="square_holder">` to `</div>` so it ends that div, rather than starting a new one.

Comment: fiddlesticks. i suppose i should really start using my browsers error console, and not just rely on stackoverflow : ]